# how to write data to mysql database and ignore a column using c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a C# program that connects to a remote mysql server and store date in a database on it.

In my db I have a column which I need it to have the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP of the server so I set the type of the column in my db to timestamp and the default value to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP the problem is when I ignore this column in my command I get this error "column count doesn't match value count at row 1" and if I send empty value, the value in the db becomes like this "0000-00-00 00:00:00".

here is my code

```
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.CommandText = 
    "INSERT INTO tbCard VALUES (@id,@Phone, @username, @CardDate)";

DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "");
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", number);
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName);
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CardDate", ""); // here is the problem

DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand();
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.Clear();
```

I don't want to send the current time and date of the machine because I want to use the server time.

Comment: `INSERT INTO tbCard VALUES (@id, @Phone, @username, now())` ?

Comment: `now()` is server side function, it will return current server's time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify which columns you want to insert and omit the column:

```
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tbCard(id, Phone, username) VALUES (@id,@Phone, @username)";

DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", "");
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", number);
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", UserName);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use an INSERT statement without saying which columns receives the values then you need to pass all the values for all the columns in the order in which the columns are defined in the table.

To avoid this problem just specify the column's names before the VALUES statement

```
string cmdText = @"INSERT INTO tbCard (col1, col2, col3) 
                   VALUES (@id, @Phone, @username)";
DBConnectMySQL.DBCommand.CommandText = cmdText;
```

Also, if the ID column is an AUTO-INCREMENT column, then you shouldn't pass also this column and its value.